# apache/htaccess: how to show one content for any file-name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my forms into different addresses e g thanks-a.html, thanks-b.html, ... (to be able to set different goals for google analytics) but the page content would be always the same.

My idea is to have an index.html page in a folder and .htaccess file that shows index.html when any none-existing filename is called. Can somebody help me write that htaccess?

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled

In your .htaccess file put the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Where index.html is the page you want to show.  This is different from what the other Andrew says because it seems to me you want to redirect everyone to a specific page, not a 404 page.  Redirecting to a 404 is fine if you want that HTTP status but in this case I think the author wants to display actual content, in which case the request should certainly be accompanied by a 200 response.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be just to use an ErrorDocument for 404:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourFolder/index.html
```

mod_rewrite would be better semantically, but it wouldn't be simpler than this.

Comment: This will make the 'success' page the 404.  Not ideal under any circumstances.

Comment: Which is why I don't really recommend doing this in this manner.  The "requirement," however, was to show a specific page for any nonexistent file.  A better solution, IMO, would be at least to have a specific pattern (like thanks-(.*).html) and use mod_rewrite, much as the other responders have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteRule` in your htaccess file. This is a very basic one that will redirect any paths that don't exist:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /yourfile.html [L]
```

This is pretty much the condition for WordPress.

You could modify this further by checking that the file is prefixed with 'thankyou-' or something. A nice comprehensive list of htaccess tips and tricks can be found here: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#wor2